# how to estimate phylogeny without using DNA sequences?

Tags: phylogenetics

I am new to bioinformatics, I am reading ‘Analysis of Phylogenetics Second Edition and Evolution with R’ from Emmanuel Paradis.

I can create phylogeny from DNA sequences, by first calculating the distances and then using (ie nj() function).

My question is: if instead of DNA I have trait data (ie height and weight of species), how can I estimate a phylogeny? (is the same process valid? somehow calculate distances and pass that to nj()?)

Comment: You want to make a phylogeny with only two non-independant data points per species?

Comment: let's say I have 20 data points for weight and length, and 3 or 4 species, is it doable? (I am curious how, either using R or paper...)

Comment: Morphological taxonomies are typically based on presence or absence of different anatomical traits. While you could technically calculate a phylogeny based on size and weight, it seems unlikely to produce an accurate or valid phylogeny. Sometimes distantly related species have similar body sizes (raccoons and opossums). In other cases, related species might have dramatically different sizes. For example, the round-eared elephant shrew (Macroscelides micus) resembles a small mouse (weighing around 28g), but it is more closely related to elephants than rodents.

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/her/tree-of-life/a/building-an-evolutionary-tree